# Refresh Flash-content and FlashVars with jQuery

Tags: jquery, flash, twitter-bootstrap, flashvars

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap (& jQuery which comes in package with it)  for building a web-app which contains a Flash-object.
What I need is this:

I need to refresh the container with Flash-object and pass new FlashVars values to it.
**(Without refreshing the entire page)**

I would even say I just need to refresh the container with Flash and create it from scratch with new flashvars (I currently use swfobject for publishing Flash).

Is there any way I can do this using jQuery or anyting else?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You should maybe look at useing ExternalInterface to push new values into the movie. I think flashVars are by definition the values Flash receives when it loads, so you'd have to load the movie again to get different flashVars. You can't even write to the flashVars object from within Flash.

Comment: The problem is that i NEED to completely refresh flash content without refreshing the entire page. ExternalInterface is a good work-around, but it's not a clean solution. But I could find one. I just posted it in the topic below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I just found a solution.

http://learnswfobject.com/advanced-topics/load-a-swf-using-javascript-onclick-event/

This worked for me.
Used feature of SWFObject